# Nock is not intercepting API call in Redux test

Tags: node.js, tdd, redux, nock

I'm trying to test an api call in a redux app. The code pretty much follows the pattern outlined in the *Async Action Creators* section of the redux docs:

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html

The gist of it is that you use *redux-mock-store* to record and assert against any actions that are triggered.

This is the whole test, using nock to mock the api call:

```
import React from 'React'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import expect from 'expect';
import expectJSX from 'expect-jsx';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import nock from 'nock'
expect.extend(expectJSX);

import * as types from '../../constants/Actions'

describe('Async Search Actions', () => {
    const thunkMiddleware = [ thunk ];
     /* use redux-mock-store here */
    const mockStore = configureMockStore(thunkMiddleware);


    describe('The fetchArtistData action creator should', () => {

            afterEach(() => {
                nock.cleanAll()
            })

        it('Should fire off a ARTIST action when fetch is done', (done) => {
            nock('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com')
                .get('/2.0/')
                .query({method: 'artist.search', artist: 'ho', api_key: 'abc123', format: 'json', limit: 5})
                .reply(200, 
                      {
                        fake: true
                      }
                   )



            const expectedActions = [
                { type: types.ARTIST, artists: {
                        fake: true
                    } 
                }
            ];

            let store = mockStore([], expectedActions, done);
            store.dispatch(fetchArtist('ho'))

        });

    });

});
```

But it seems that the real lastFm api is called when the test is run...real data is returned from lastFm rather than the fake nock response.

This is the action creator itself:

```
export function fetchArtist(search) {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetch(`http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.search&artist=${search}&api_key=abc123&format=json&limit=5`)
            .then(handleErrors)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => { dispatch(ArtistData(searchTerm, json)) })
            .catch(handleServerErrors)
    }
}
```

The assertion fails because the live lastFM response is not the same as the response I'm expecting as per the `expectedActions` object..

I've tried assigning the nock to a variable and log it out.The log shows this:

Nock seems to be adding port 80 to the url, not sure if this is causing the actual API to not be mocked:

```
    keyedInterceptors: Object{GET http://ws.audioscrobbler.com:80/2.0/?
method=artist.search&artist=john&api_key=abc123&format=json&limit=5
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: Are you running this in node or the browser? I don't believe nock works in browsers, only node

Comment: Ah ok, that's the problem then, I'm running the tests on PhantomJs

Comment: Looks like nock doesn't like browser fetch https://github.com/node-nock/nock/issues/409. Going to try and switch to fetch-mock as suggested for the time being

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I've looked everywhere and can't figure it out

Comment: Did you find a solution? My nock is also not mocking.

Comment: I had the same problem, 'whatwg-fetch' was the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645242/nock-is-not-intercepting-my-request/37668316#37668316

Answer (score 3):

In order to use nock you must run your tests in node (using Jest or mocha), nock overrides node http behavior and for that reason it only works in node and not in browsers (like PhantomJS).

For example the link you pointed out is using Jest and first lines there are explicit about the node environment. Therefore, nock will work as a charm.
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html

> **Setting Up**
>
> We recommend Jest as the testing engine. Note that it runs
> in a Node environment, so you won't have access to the DOM.

As I see you can:

- run your tests in a node environment
- or use a different library to mock like [fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass just base URL to the main `nock` function and separate the URL path portion out into the `.get()` method.

```
nock('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com')
  .get('/2.0/')
  .query({
    method: 'artist.search',
    artist: 'bob',
    api_key: 'somekey123',
    format: 'json',
    limit: '5'
  })
  .reply(200, {fake: true})
```

I was able to get a fake response with the above code.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'd tried this - I'm still getting real data back from last fm with this configuration

Comment: OK well you'll need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as there's something else disconnected here but difficult to guess what that might be.

Comment: Ok added some more detail

Comment: Looks like url path mismatch /202/ vs /2.0/

Comment: That was a typo unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

add .log(console.log) after nock , so you will get exact expected and current url.
example:

```
     nock("http://localhost")
.log(console.log)
.persist()
.get("/api/config")
.reply(200, { data: 1234 })
```